# Autoresize Height and Width Proportionally Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios6, interface-builder, autoresize

I have a UIImageView that is set to autoresize it's height based on the height of the Superview, i.e. when the In Call Status bar comes down. How do I make the entire view resize proportionally so that the width of the UIImageView changes when the height changes?

I would like to do this in Interface Builder, but programmatically can be used as well.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you select the view in IB and go to the section related to the view settings and check mark the box next to auto resize ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in iOS 6 is to use the (new in iOS 6) autolayout feature. It is very easy to make a view's width always be a fixed proportion of its height.

Otherwise you'll have to detect the change in your view controller's `layoutSubviews` and use code to resize the UIImageView.

However, consider the alternative of letting *image* resize rather than the whole image view. If you give the UIImageView the right `contentMode`, it will automatically resize the image proportionally if the view's height changes.

Comment: Perfect! I set the contentMode from "Scale to Fit" (the default) to "Aspect Fit" and it works perfectly.